# Compute the value of $ \sqrt{e} $ with accuracy of 0.001 by using the Taylor Series of $ e^x $

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to solve the following problem: 
Compute the value of $ \sqrt{e} $ with accuracy of 0.001 by using the Taylor Series of $ e^x $.
Computing the value without a given precision is no problem as I know that
$$ e^x = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} $$
The remainder equals $ R_N(x)=\frac{f^{n+1}(c)}{(n+1)!}\cdot(x-x_0)^{n+1}  $
As we don't know c we can't use this to estimate an absolute value for the error so we replace $ f^{n+1}(c) $ with M where M is the estimated max of our function.
I decided to choose $ M = 3 $ as $ e \approx 3 \land \sqrt{e} < e $
In the end I come up with $$ R_n(x)= \frac {M \cdot (x-x_0)^n}{(n+1)!} \Rightarrow R_n(0.5)=\frac{3\cdot 0.5^n}{(n+1)!} \Rightarrow \frac{3\cdot 0.5^n}{(n+1)!} < 0.001 $$
When I solve this by brute force I'm getting $ n \ge 5 $ but this gives me a precision of 3 decimal places.
$$ e^x = \sum_{i=0}^5 \frac{x^n}{n!} \Rightarrow f(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} \Rightarrow f(0.5)= 1.648698 $$
$$ e^{0.5} = 1.64872 $$
You can see that this is correct to 3 decimal places. By playing a bit around I found out that it should be enough to go up to n=3.
$$ e^x = \sum_{i=0}^3 \frac{x^n}{n!} \Rightarrow f(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} \Rightarrow f(0.5)= 1.646 $$.
I'm feeling that I'm missing something simple but important but I can't find my mistake.

Comment: What is the problem? You find an approximation and it's good to $0.00002$ which is better than you need. The estimate for the error is just an upper bound so don't expect it to give the minimum $n$ for which the error is less than $0.001$.

Comment: Well you're right. The real precision is better than I wanted it. From quality perspective this is a good thing but from the needed time perspective of calculating the derivates (of a maybe more complicated function) it's a bad thing. I don't want to calculate the first 5 items if I only need 3.    
So my question would be: Is there any error in my calculated number of needed items and/or is there a way to calculate this more precise to reduce the number of unneded/unwanted series items?

Comment: Moreover, following what Winther wrote, you proved that using only $n=3$ is not sufficient as the third digit after the dot is not correct.

Comment: Yes that would be nice, but there is no general method to finding such a minimum $n$. Atleast not one that is computationally fast, you would need to do something like finding the exact value (to desired accuracy) and then checking $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. As you can see this would require much more computation. The advantage of Taylor's formula is that you get a *an* $n$ for which you then *know* that the accuracy is good enough.

Comment: Okay perfect. Thank you @Winther as mathcounterexamples.net wrote I may have misunderstood something. I thought (and read) that 0.001 = 0.1*10^-2 = 2 decimals precision not 3. So is my whole expectation of (only) 2 decimal points precision false?

Comment: Could you explain where my fallacy is? Is my whole expectation of 0.001 means 2 decimals precision wrong (and if so how to say it correctly) or is it just wrong in this case?

Comment: Note that your value $n$ depends on $M$. Choosing a smaller $M$ might result in a smaller $n$, but even for the safe value $M=2$ you would need $n=5$, because wiith $n=4$ the error term would be $0.001042$. With $M=\sqrt{3}$ you would get $n=4$.

Comment: $$ \begin{align}R_{n}(x)&=\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{i!} =\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+\sum_{i=n+2}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{i!} =\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\left(1+\sum_{i=n+2}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{i!}\,x^{i-n-1}\right) \\ &=\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\color{red}{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)!\,x^{i}}{(n+1+i)!}\right) \quad\longrightarrow\,M(x)} \\ M\left(\frac12\right)&=1+\frac{1/2}{4}+\frac{1/4}{4*5}\approx1.1375 \end{align} $$

Comment: $$ R_3\left(\frac12\right)=\frac{1.1375}{2^4*4!}\approx0.006 \quad\&\quad R_4\left(\frac12\right)=\frac{1.1375}{2^5*5!}\approx0.0003 $$